# How to hide radio communications between airplanes?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, signal-processing, radio

I have 2 airplanes and I would like completely hide the communications between them.

There is a possible way that this communications would not be detected by our radio receivers around the world? Would be possible to simple hide it?

What alternative technology can be used achieve this? And why we would not detect this alternative technology?

Anyone with Telecom background? :)
I found this interesting answer that can give some context: [Alternatives to electromagnetism for communication?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114206/alternatives-to-electromagnetism-for-communication/114207)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is speculating about new science in an essentially unscientific scenario. An F&SF forum would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes I'm speculating about UFOs tech but my scenario is possible and the questions are physics related. I really would like to see scientific insights about this scenario.

Comment: Your suggestion is generally held not to be possible. The thread you link to made that clear. Bringing in UFOs just makes things worse.

Comment: I can change the question to don't use UFO assumptions then. Can I do it and keep the physics related questions?

Comment: A very similar question has already been asked and answered, as you linked to yourself. What specific aspect of physics, not covered by that question, would you want to ask about here? (If that aspect is asked but not answered there, then it is unlikely to be answered here either).

Comment: In this scenario I have 3 questions that was not answered in that linked question. Come on, let's be more open minded. Breakthrough Initiatives organization are spending billions in research for intelligent life and even if they can't find any, we will get the benefits of the new technology they developing for it.

Comment: One problem with any interstellar communication is that it takes such a long time. You can't have a casual conversation with someone a light-year away, unless you're *very* patient. ;) Or you're using physics beyond our current theories (which is off-topic on this site).

Comment: If they are a civilization then they are not UFO. They are identified.

Comment: I didn't mention interstellar, it's really off-topic.

Comment: Oh, ok. You're just talking about communication between ships, once they get here. That's pretty easy: just use a laser beam, or tight microwave beam. The much harder problem is how to hide the energy from the engines. It takes a lot of energy to travel quickly around a star system (and even more to travel quickly between stars), unless you use physics well outside the mainstream. BTW, when you reply to a comment you should use the `@UserName` syntax to ensure that the person you're replying to gets notified. (You get notified automatically because it's your post).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One does not have to step outside normal rf communications technology to find ways of communication that would not be apparent. The field of encryption is replete with possibilities.

One normally thinks of encryption as a method of hiding the informational content of a message without hiding the actual existence of the message, but this is not always the case. I'll give just one of many possible examples.

Any rf reciever is plagued by noise from many possible sources including the cosmic microwave background which permeates the entire universe. It is possible to generate an rf signal that resembles noise but that is actually deterministic (the field of non-linear dynamics offers many possibilities).  Suppose one designs an rf generator that can superpose an information packet on a segment of deterministic noise generated by a specific non-linear algorithm. The signal would appear to be noise to anyone with an rf receiver not designed in line with this particular algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your direct and detailed answer! So I can encrypt my rf transmission as a "noise" to almost hide it, right? I'm sofware developer with some experience with Neural Networks, I guess would be possible to use AI to analyse and identify the RF signals as really noise or encrypted messages... of course, would be necessary a properly trained neural network.

Comment: @Felipe Right.  Yes it is possible to detect deterministic noise but not likely unless you suspect it.  The down votes you are getting are due to your use of UFOs in your question.  I suggest you edit your question to avoid reference to UFOs.  Otherwise your question (as well as my answer) will continue to attract down votes.

Comment: Hi I just changed it. It became very uninteresting, but since your answer was very nice I decided to change the question and avoid the speculative part. Thank you!